# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am getting this error "Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

```
 var arrItems = {
    'product1': [],
    'product2': [],
    'product3': []
};

var temArr = {};
var dataFor = "";

function fnAddItem(elm, itemInd, rem) {

    if (elm != "" && elm != undefined) {
        var _name = $(elm).attr("data-name");
        var _id = $(elm).attr("data-id");
        var _in = $(elm).attr("data-index");
        itemInd = _in;

        *arrItems[dataFor][_in] = {
            'name': _name,
            'id': _id,
            'index': _in
        };*
        console.log(arrItems[dataFor][_in]);
    }

    var strHtml = "";

    $.each(arrItems[dataFor], function(key, value) {
        if (value['name'] != undefined || value['name'] != null)
            strHtml += '<div onclick="fnRemoveItem(this,0,\'' + dataFor + '\');" class="__selected_item" data-remove="' + value['index'] + '"><span>' + (value['index'] == 1 ? value['index'] : "") + value['name'] + (value['index'] == 3 ? value['index'] : "") + '</span><span class="x">&times;</span></div>';
        console.log(strHtml);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where in the code is the error occurring?

Comment: arrItems[dataFor][_in] = {
            'name': _name,
            'id': _id,
            'index': _in
        };

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like you have not defined any value for `dataFor`. In the code the value you get for `arrItems[dataFor]` is `undefined` because since `dataFor=''` so basically you are doing `arrItems['']` which does not exist.

`dataFor` needs to be set to one of the 3 values in the `arrItems` object for the code to work.

Comment: Can you tell how can I set the values  in `arrItems`

Comment: This is my HTML code `<div class="__req_radio_box">
                            <div class="__radios" data-name="Furniture" data-id="ITEM001" data-index="0" onclick="fnAddItem(this);"><input name="service_request" id="1" type="radio" value="Furniture Repair"><label for="1">Furniture Repair</label></div><div class="__radios" data-name="Plumbing" data-id="ITEM002" data-index="0" onclick="fnAddItem(this);"><input name="service_request" id="2" type="radio" value="Plumbing Issue"><label for="2">Plumbing Issue</label</div></div>`

Comment: Looks like you are setting values correctly, its about retrieving the values which is the issue.